# Angular material md-menu issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material and show a md-menu icon on my page. When i click on that icon it opens trigger properly but when i click on page or that trigger then it will not close. I have added md-menu in ng-repeat.

```
<div class ="who-we-are" ng-repeat="data in whoWeAre" flex-lg = "50" flex-md = "50" flex-gt-lg = "50" flex-sm ="100" >
            <md-menu hide show-sm ng-show="{{data.number}}">
              <md-button aria-label="Open demo menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
              <i md-menu-origin class="fa fa-phone"></i>

              </md-button>
              <md-menu-content width="6">
                <md-menu-item>
                  <md-button >
                    {{data.number}}
                  </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
              </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
          </div>
```

Comment: You want this type of menu http://codepen.io/jbltx/pen/VYybVr

Comment: @PareshGami Yes i want this type of menu but it will not close trigger  when i clicked outside due to ng-repeat.

Comment: if you dont use ng-repeat for creating menu then menu is closed when i am click other screen area right?

Comment: Paresh Gami very nice pen you have there? you did that? you created your own md-menu with more options?

Comment: @PareshGami yes it is working properly when ng-repeat is not addded

Comment: @RichaDhanuka can you create codepen for that